# extracting attribute values of <div> tag in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am crawling a website with scrapy.
i have come across a situation where i need to extract an attribute value of div tag. eg 
i need to extract "lmnop" from the web page

I have tried few css selectors but they return an empty list.
for the above eg. i wrote a css selector as:

`response.css('div.blahblah::attr(abc)').extract()`

For this piece of HTML code the expected output is shown below

Code:`<div class="searching-result" data-id="somehashvalue" abc="xyz"></div>`

Expected output:
["somehashvalue"]

Comment: What is the site that you are scraping?

Comment: Check the source HTML (the source, not the DOM you see when you use a browser inspector), to make sure the target HTML code exists as is, and is not generated by JavaScript code. And definitely share some code that we can use to reproduce your issue.

Comment: https://en.e-podroznik.pl/
On this website, after filling the Start and End point and making a connection. i am trying to extract all the stops that are intermediate stops between these end points. and for that i need resId which is inside a div tag as an attribute. @ Pasindu Gamarachchi

Comment: @Gallaecio Yes it is showing in the page source that we get after right click and selection "view page source"

Comment: In your spider, save `response.text` to a file to verify that Scrapy gets the same HTML code. If so, please, update your question with an actual target fragment HTML and your actual CSS selector.

Comment: @Gallaecio Yes i did that, and it turns out that it is surely present in the source code.

```
<div class="searching-result" data-triggerPassengerSearch="false"data-parcelOnlyByCustomerServiceModalTitle="tylko przez infolinię" data-parcelOnlyByCustomerServiceModalContent="Chcesz wysłać paczkę? Zadzwoń pod numer , aby zarezerwować przewóz przesyłki." data-resId="619b64ab7f534b24ab5cbd770970fe33" data-detailspath="/public/searchingResultExtended.do?tabToken=90090cc93739b8466a07091452ea6778&amp;resultId=619b64ab7f534b24ab5cbd770970fe3">
```
I am interested in value of "data-resId" attribute.

Comment: What CSS expression are you using that is failing?

Comment: @Gallaecio
when i use 
```response.css('div.searching-result').extract()```
or 
```response.xpath('/html//div[@class = "searching-result"]').extract()```
i am getting a huge response text but to access the attribute inside the div i am using
```response.css('div.searching-result::attr(data-resId)').extract()```
This returns empty list

Comment: Thankyou, i figured it out
```response.css('div.searching-result').xpath('@data-resid').getall()```
This selector works perfectly.
@Gallaecio

Comment: Your failing expression had ‘resId’ instead of the ‘resid’ (lowercase i) of your working expression, may that have been the issue?

Comment: @Gallaecio
No that wasn't the issue. i had tried both. maybe some other error.